Why is the shape for this tensor suddenly different for a pytorch tensor in the library from NNI?
I am using the NNI library for pruning a neural network.
In the compression it uses a function, _metric_fuse. In this function an error happens. The error is
RuntimeError: output with shape [12, 1] doesn't match the broadcast shape [12, 12]

The function looks like this:
def _metric_fuse(metrics: _METRICS) -> torch.Tensor:
    # mean all metric value
    fused_metric = None
    count = 0
    for _, module_metrics in metrics.items():
        for _, target_metric in module_metrics.items():
            print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
            print(fused_metric)
            print(target_metric)
            if fused_metric is not None:
                fused_metric += target_metric
            else:
                fused_metric = target_metric.clone()
            count += 1
    assert fused_metric is not None
    return fused_metric / count

The error happens in fused_metric += target_metric. The printed tensors look like this:
None

tensor([[1.6796e-06],
        [2.3090e-07],
        [6.1086e-07],
        [1.5183e-07],
        [3.7875e-09],
        [8.8616e-07],
        [6.5265e-07],
        [9.6800e-08],
        [8.1835e-07],
        [2.9000e-07],
        [1.1585e-07],
        [5.4605e-08]], device='cuda:0')

-----------------------------------------------------------
tensor([[1.6796e-06],
        [2.3090e-07],
        [6.1086e-07],
        [1.5183e-07],
        [3.7875e-09],
        [8.8616e-07],
        [6.5265e-07],
        [9.6800e-08],
        [8.1835e-07],
        [2.9000e-07],
        [1.1585e-07],
        [5.4605e-08]], device='cuda:0')

tensor([[3.4065e-06],
        [2.0305e-06],
        [2.3129e-06],
        [1.8377e-06],
        [6.3720e-05],
        [3.4308e-06],
        [2.4689e-06],
        [2.8250e-06],
        [1.7304e-06],
        [4.2669e-06],
        [5.7278e-07],
        [4.4945e-07]], device='cuda:0')

-----------------------------------------------------------
tensor([[5.0860e-06],
        [2.2613e-06],
        [2.9237e-06],
        [1.9896e-06],
        [6.3724e-05],
        [4.3169e-06],
        [3.1215e-06],
        [2.9218e-06],
        [2.5488e-06],
        [4.5569e-06],
        [6.8863e-07],
        [5.0406e-07]], device='cuda:0')

tensor([[2.3013e-06],
        [2.6519e-07],
        [6.8275e-07],
        [1.2156e-07],
        [8.3832e-09],
        [1.1710e-06],
        [7.8374e-07],
        [8.3750e-08],
        [8.2380e-07],
        [3.3028e-07],
        [1.9342e-07],
        [1.1004e-07]], device='cuda:0')

-----------------------------------------------------------
tensor([[7.3874e-06],
        [2.5265e-06],
        [3.6065e-06],
        [2.1111e-06],
        [6.3732e-05],
        [5.4879e-06],
        [3.9053e-06],
        [3.0056e-06],
        [3.3726e-06],
        [4.8872e-06],
        [8.8205e-07],
        [6.1409e-07]], device='cuda:0')

tensor([[4.2203e-06, 2.2458e-06, 5.0584e-06, 5.3744e-06, 5.3401e-05, 5.1009e-06,
         4.3903e-06, 4.8045e-06, 2.6889e-06, 7.0391e-06, 3.9046e-06, 1.3097e-06]],
       device='cuda:0')

nni==3.0rc1
torch==2.0.1
torchaudio==2.0.2
torchvision==0.15.2
transformers==4.33.1
python = 3.10.15

So for some reason it changes from [12,1] to [12,12] which confuses me. Anybody got a clue what could be the issue?

One of the target_metric tensor (the last printed one) has a different shape, as evidenced by the output of your prints. As to why, you have to explain where do these tensors come from, what are you trying to do with them
